# How can I remove row after compare value between the columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame looks like this.

```
Doc1 Doc2
a     b
ab    b
abc   b
a     c
b     c
b     d
dc    d
c     a
cfg   c
d     a
```

I would like to remove the row by removing the value in Doc1 that is not contained in Doc2.

the expected results will look like this

```
Doc1 Doc2
a     b
a     c
b     c
b     d
c     a
d     a
```

and here is my code that I have tried

```
df = df[~df["Doc1"].isin(df["doc2"])]
```

but there is nothing happened with the data frame

do i understand the wrong thing?

Comment: I think you meant `df = df[df["Doc1"].isin(df["Doc2"])]`, without the `~`. But that works, so what is the problem? What are your doc1 and doc2 _actually_?

Comment: your logic is ok.  make sure the two columns are of the same dtype - pandas won't consider a column whose dtype is "Object" (meaning contains nulls / mixed) and a dtype "String" as having any values in common.  `col.astype(type)` converts the column